Fatal error - need some advice to identify what's happening
My live site seems to be falling offline most mornings, with a Fatal Error email from Wordpress received. The error that shows is
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 234 of the file /homepages/21/d802502790/htdocs/clickandbuilds/u3aoliva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php. Error message: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [unauthorized: Authorization failed: CiviCRM APIv4 (MembershipType::get)
I've checked the list of membership types (in Administer > CiviMember > Membership Types) and all ok. I've searched the membership list to check for any unrecognised types, and again all ok.
This error doesn't appear in the downloaded CiviCRM log file. But perhaps unconnected, each entry starts with an authorisation error.
2024-11-06 06:14:09+0000  [debug] $API Request Authorization failed = #0 /homepages/21/d802502790/htdocs/clickandbuilds/u3aoliva/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(148): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("API Request Authorization failed", TRUE)
Any tips for where to look?

If it's happening about the same time every day, I wonder if it might be related to a scheduled task running then? The task might be triggering the permission problem. Just a thought.

No cron jobs set up (keep getting a message to tell me to do that). No background scheduled processes I can see. It’s around the same time - between 05:00 and 08:00. Very low usage site so unconnected to user or admin access.
